# How to populate spinner from variably resource string name based on user input?

Tags: android

I need to populate a spinner from string-array resource based on user input (i.e: fruits,vegetables,animals).

```
<string-array name="fruits">
   <item>Apple</item>
   <item>Orange</item>
   <item>Mango</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="vegetables">
   <item>Cabbage</item>
   <item>Lettuce</item>
   <item>Spinach</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="animals">
   <item>Lion</item>
   <item>Tiger</item>
   <item>Bear</item>
</string-array>
```

For example, if the input is "fruits"

```
String input = "fruits";
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireActivity(), getContext().getResources().getInteger(getResources().getIdentifier(input, "string-array", getActivity().getPackageName())), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

But I got this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: The second argument in the `getIdentifier()` call would be just `"array"`, not `"string-array"`.

Comment: Although change to "array" didn't resolve the error, the answer in other thread did the trick. Sorry, I've tried to look at many resolutions before, but seemed have missed that one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it clear that you needed to remove the `getInteger()` call. I was just pointing out the `"string-array"` difference because most people miss that. Anyhoo, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!